# Derived Tensor Product in Terms of Homotopy Groups

Tags: homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, derived-functors, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

Let $R$ be a ring and $R-\operatorname{Mod}$
the category of $R$-modules. The tensor product
functor $- \otimes_R -: (R-\operatorname{Mod}) \times
(R-\operatorname{Mod}) \to R-\operatorname{Mod}-R$
has an analogon in derived category of
the category of $R$-modules
$- \otimes^L -: D(R-\operatorname{Mod}) \times
D(R-\operatorname{Mod}) \to R-D(\operatorname{Mod}-R)$

We write suggestively for two $R$-
modules $M, N$ which represents certain
classes $[M], [N]$ in derived category

$$ \operatorname{Tor}^L_i (M, N)=
H_i(M \otimes_R N)  $$

to remind that we can calculate
the $i$-th grade or representant of
$ \operatorname{Tor}^L_i (M, N)$
by taking an projective resolution
$P^{\bullet} \to M$ (resp. injective resolution
$N \to I^{\bullet}$), tensor the proj resolution
with $N$ (resp tensor the inj resolution with
$M$) and calculate $i$-th homology.

Now [on this wiki site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_tensor_product#Derived_tensor_product_in_derived_ring_theory) is clamed a statement which I don't understand. It is stated in terms of *homotopy groups (!)* that

$$ \pi_i(M \otimes_R^L N) =   \operatorname{Tor}^L_i (M, N)  $$

By defition $\operatorname{Tor}^L_i$ is just the notation for $i$-th derived part $R^i(- \otimes^L -)$ of the tensor functor in derived context. And I'm not sure which meaning do have here the
*homotopy groups* $\pi_i(-)$ and why the claim before
is true.

I guess that the *homotopy groups* $\pi_i(-)$ are involved
here since the derived category
$D(R-\operatorname{Mod})$ has natural structure of a
triangulated category and therefore
we can associate to it a homotopy category
$Ho(D(R-\operatorname{Mod}))$ where introducing
homotopy groups make sense.

This category contains also the notation of
$n$-sphere analoga and therefore formally
homotopy groups $\pi_i(X)$ make sense for every
$X \in D(R-\operatorname{Mod})$.

But nevertheless I not understand why after passing to homotopy
category of $D(\operatorname{Mod}-R)$ the identity

$$ \pi_i(M \otimes^L N) =   \operatorname{Tor}^L_i (M, N)  $$

holds?
Does it more generally for every derived functor
$F: D(R-\operatorname{Mod}) \to D(R-\operatorname{Mod})$
and every $X \in D(R-\operatorname{Mod})$ hold

$$ \pi_i(F(X)) =   R^iF(X)? $$

If yes, how to show that?

Comment: I suspect that regarding them as discrete spectra might make the derived category just have the expected structure: hom-tensor adjunction with the smash product, homotopy groups as homology, etc.

Comment: They are about *left* derived functors, and you could read Lurie's Higher Algebra, Thm 7.1.2.13.

Comment: This is just notation, people sometimes write $\pi_*(X)$ instead of $H_*(X)$. One reason this is good notation is that $H_n(X)=[R(n),X]$, where $R(n)$ is a complex with $R$ concentrated in degree $n$ and zeroes elsewhere.

If $X$ was a spectrum instead of a complex, then $\pi_n(X)= [\mathbb{S}^n,X]$, so with this notation we think of $D(R)$ as being analogous to the stable homotopy category.

Comment: In particular, you aren't passing to the homotopy category $D(R)$, $D(R)$ is already a kind of homotopy category. You can work in a fancy setting where $D(R)$ is a special case of something to do with spectra but you certainly don't have to.

Comment: I see, so we regard $D(R)$ already as *the homotopy theory* (assoc to cat of chain maps) where it make sense to talk about homotopy groups $\pi_i(-)$? And the classes represented by $R(n)$ (that is $R$ shifted to degree $n$) are here exactly those objects which 'play the role' of $n$-sphere from usual topological homotopy groups?

Comment: On the linked wikipedia page the
$R$-modules $N, M$ are named as 
"discrete specra". Is there a natural
way to see $R$-modules or say chain 
complexes of $R$-modules as "spectra"?

Comment: @James Cameron: You remarked that one can also
"work in a fancy setting where $D(R)$ is a special 
case of something to do with spectra." 
Could you make it precise. Does it have 
something to do with considering $D(R)$ as
a $\infty$-category?

Comment: @user7391733 You don' need to work with $\infty$-categories, this is older. You can look at modules for the Eilenberg-Maclane spectrum $HR$, and $\textrm{Ho}( \textrm{Mod}-HR)$ is equivalent as tensor triangulated categories to $D(R)$. In fact, $\textrm{Mod}-HR$ and chain complexes of $R$-modules are equivalent as monoidal model categories. A key word is "Stable Dold-Kan Correspondence".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this is due to the Stable Dold-Kan correspondence. A core principle of stable homotopy theory is that it contains the usual theory of rings and modules.
If $R$ is a commutative ring, then the Eilenberg-Mac Lane spectrum $HR$ is a commutative ring spectrum. One one hand, you can define the homotopy category $\mathcal{D}(R)$ of derived $R$-modules in which quasi-isomorphisms become isomorphisms. On the other hand, you can define the homotopy category $\mathsf{Mod}_{HR}$ of modules over $HR$ in spectra, in which stable equivalences are isomorphisms.

Now the homotopy categories above are equivalent and homotopy groups correspond to homology groups. This is really a stabilization of the usual Dold-Kan correspondence. The stabilization of simplicial $R$-modules naturally provides a model for $HR$-modules and the stabilization of non-negative chain complexes provides a model for $\mathcal{D}(R)$.

Even better, the equivalence is symmetric monoidal at the level of homotopy categories endowed with their respective derived tensor product. This shows that algebras and modules in either categories correspond (without coherence data).

Schwede-Shipley formalized the equivalence at the level of model categories (being Quillen equivalent is something stronger than just having equivalent homotopy categories), see [Theorem 5.1.6](https://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Ebshipley/classTopFinal.pdf). Shipley then provides an explicit zig-zag of Quillen equivalences between the model categories and show they are weakly monoidally equivalent. This allows to show that the model categories of algebras and modules are equivalent, see [here](https://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Ebshipley/zdga17.pdf). You already encounter troubles for commutative algebras and prefer to consider $\mathbb{E}_\infty$-algebras (commutative and associative up to higher homotopies).

Even better, Lurie transfer the arguments of Schwede-Shipley and show that the corresponding $\infty$-categories between $HR$-modules and derived $R$-modules are equivalent as symmetric monoidal $\infty$-categories, see [7.1.2.13](https://www.math.ias.edu/%7Elurie/papers/HA.pdf). This is a stronger result as before as now we can say that $\mathcal{O}$-algebras (and also their modules) correspond. Here $\mathcal{O}$ is (any!) $\infty$-operad. You can again transfer the arguments of Shipley in $\infty$-categorical settings to make the equivalence concrete on objects, see [Corollary 4.4](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.09407.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your enlightening answer, unfortunately 
I hadn't enough time before for a carefully reading, so sorry for
my delayed feedback. I have several questions about some aspects in your 
answer:

Comment: You wrote in second paragraph that "the
homotopy categories above (ie $D(R)$ and $Mod_{HR} \subset Spectra$)
are equivalent and homotopy groups 
correspond to homology groups. This is really a stabilization 
of the usual Dold-Kan correspondence. "

Comment: What do mean by "homotopy groups 
correspond to homology groups"? Do you mean by "homotopy groups"  the 
homotopy groups of chains in $Ch_{\ge 0}(R)$, which
we regard as objects of $D(R)$? And as homologies
just the $[\mathcal{S}^n, M]$ for sphere spectrum $\mathcal{S}^n$, right?

Comment: Also, why this is called "stabilization" of 
the usual Dold-Kan correspondence?

Comment: I meant that if $X$ is an $HR$-module, and $\theta(X)$ is its corresponding chain complex over $R$, then $\pi_*(X)\cong H_*(\theta(X))$.

Comment: It is sometimes called stable Dold-Kan correspondence because the usual Dold-Kan correspondence gives an equivalence of categories between simplicial $R$-modules $\mathsf{sMod}_R$ and non-negative chain complexes $\mathsf{Ch}^{\geq 0}_R$. If you stabilize $\mathsf{sMod}_R$, you get $HR$-modules, if you stabilize $\mathsf{Ch}^{\geq 0}_R$ you get unbounded chain complexes over $R$ up to quasi-isomorphism, i.e. $\mathcal{D}(R)$.

Comment: Could you give a reference where this identification $\pi_*(X)\cong H_*(\theta(X))$ for $X \in \mathsf{Mod}_{HR}$ is proved? I'm not sure how we obtain this as consequence from stable Dold-Kan.

Comment: Here is one I guess: B.1.9 in https://homepages.math.uic.edu/%7Ebshipley/classTopFinal.pdf