# Discrete Spectra

Tags: homotopy-theory, derived-categories, spectra

What is a "*discrete [spectra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(topology))*" in context of homotopy theory/ derived category theory? It is for example mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_tensor_product#Derived_tensor_product_in_derived_ring_theory). Although it looks quite "googleable" I found nowhere a precise definition.
Remark: question is closely related with discussion
here: [Derived Tensor Product in Terms of Homotopy Groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222198/derived-tensor-product-in-terms-of-homotopy-groups) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, it means a spectrum whose homotopy groups all vanish except possibly for $\pi_0$.

The category of such spectra is equivalent to the category of abelian groups, via $\pi_0$ in one direction, and the Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum functor in the other direction.

Comment: So that's just a subcategory 
of the category of spectra
which satisfy this vaneshing condition on
$\pi_i(-)$ groups?

If we focus on the example from the 
linked wikipedia page. That is we consider
$R$-modules $M,N$ as "discrete spectra".

Comment: What is in this concrete example regarded as "the category
of spectra" which contain these
$M, N$ among others? Or in simple words: Why these modules $M$ and $N$ can be considered as "spectra"? We 
can naturally regard $M,N$ as objects 
in the category of chain complexes
of $R$-modules $Ch(R)$. This category 
gives my moding out chain homotopies 
the homotopy category $K(R)$. 
If we localize it with respect quasi-isomorphisms
we obtain the derived category $D(R)$.

But why and how we reagard the objects
living there naturally as "spectra"?

Comment: There is the Eilenberg-MacLane functor, which takes abelian groups and outputs discrete spectra (often denoted $HA$ for an abelian group $A$, but the convention is more and more to just write it $A$). It is lax symmetric monoidal and so an $R$-module $M$ gets sent to an $HR$-module $HM$.

Comment: But are only $R$-modules which 
we can regard in this example via application of this functor $H$
as "spectra" or does it 
extend to all chain complexes?

Comment: There is also a generalized Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum functor $D(R) \to Sp$. If you set things up properly, it induces an equivalence between $D(R)$ and $HR$-modules in $Sp$ - be careful that this is not true if you interpret the latter as a homotopy category. So the answer is that it extends to all chain complexes

Comment: Could you precise what you mean in your "be careful"-remark? Do you mean it in the sense that if we want that the generalized EML functor induces equivalence between $D(R)$ and $HR$-modules in $Sp$, then we should "forget" the homotopy category structure in $Sp$?

Comment: Or otherwise there occurs a compatibility problem between homotopy structures ($D(R)$ carries also homotopy structure)? Or is there something else what is going wrong according to your remark? Is this the point you want to stress?

Comment: What I mean is that there is a homotopy category, $ho(Sp)$, and the statement "$ho(D(R))$ is equivalent to $HR$-modules in $ho(Sp)$" is wrong, you have to use $\infty$-categories (or model categories) to make it correct.

Comment: I see, so if (or before) we not passing to $ho(-)$ everything stays fine, tight? One remark: you used notation "$ho(D(R))$". but isn't $D(R)$ already a homotopy theory intrinsically? (so $ho(D(R))=D(R)$ and the application of $ho(-)$ is redundant here?)

Comment: It depends - if you take $D(R)$ to mean the homotopy category, then no, the statement becomes "$D(R)$ is equivalent to the homotopy category of $HR$-modules in $Sp$". The point is that $D(R)$ can also be viewed as an $\infty$-category, before passing to $ho(-)$, and the statement before passing to $ho(-)$ is stronger.

Comment: Alright, I understand, thank you a lot!

Comment: I think there are still some aspects not
completely clear to me around
your remark to stay careful when 
dealing with 
the 
generalized Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum functor
$D(R) \to Sp$. You wrote that
"if we set things up properly, it induces an 
equivalence between $D(R)$ and $HR$-modules 
in $Sp$, but this is wrong if we interpret 
$Sp$ as homotopy category.

Comment: I realized only now that seemingly we
use here two different ways to associate
a homotopy category
$ho(-)$; one associates to a usual 
category $C$ which contains the notation
of a homotopy a homotopy category
$ho(C)$ and on the other hand if
the have a $\infty$-category / weak Kan
complex $K$ there is canonical machinery
associating to it a homotopy category
$ho(K)$. Of course, we can via taking 
nerve accociate to an usual category
$C$ a $\infty$-category $N(C)$. As far all
correct?

Comment: Now let come to the point where my 
confusions beginn. What do you mean
by "if we set things up properly, 
then the generalized Eilenberg-MacLane 
spectrum functor becomes an equivalence
between (...). Do you mean by this passing via
nerve to associated $\infty$-categories 
and working in "$\infty$-world" or did I 
misunderstood that point?

Comment: Futhermore as you said also this equivalence
fails if $Sp$ is interpreted as a
homotopy category. Are we here still 
regard $D(R)$ and $Sp$ as usual or
$\infty$-cats? Also, is the
construction of this "pathological" homotopy
category $ho(Sp)$ canonical, or is it
an non-canonical existment statement, that is 
that you mean that there "exist" 
a special and therefore non-canonical
way to endow $Sp$ with structure of 
a homotopy category $ho(Sp)$ such that
it's $HR$-modules 
are not equivalent to $ho(D(R))$?

Comment: I think I found the main reason for my confusion:
When you say that you apply $ho(-)$ to
$D(A)$ or $Sp$ do you *always* implicitely
consider in this case $D(A)$ (resp $Sp$)
as a $\infty$-category in the sense
of described here: 
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/derived+category#idea
Or do you mean something different? (note: at this point I not distinguish between $\infty$ and (infinity,1)-categories)

Comment: Sorry, my internet is currently not super good so I haven't read all your comments - the last one seems to hit the nail on the head though, yes !

Comment: No problem, if the interpretation 
I gave in last comment is correct, then 
my comments from 2 days before are settled.
The only point about which I'm still not sure is:
The only references on the
generalized Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum functor 
$D(R) \to Sp$ not use the language of 
$\infty$-categories. On the other hand when you
wrote that "if one sets 
things up properly, it induces an equivalence between
$D(R)$ and $HR$-modules in $Sp$. I guess 
that again by "setting things properly" you
mean again to handle
$D(R)$ and $Sp$ as $\infty$-cats, right?

Comment: If yes, do you have a reference where generalized Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum functor is discussed in setting of $\infty$-categories?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I'll try to find you references in a few days !

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: So unfortunately I'm not entirely sure of a reference that is not *Higher Algebra*, by Lurie - of course this is a great reference, but it's also a huge book (there are several other references for the analogue of this functor in other contexts, e.g. model categorical; but specifically $\infty$-categorical, this is something that should have better exposition than it currently seems to do).

Comment: For the sake of reference, let me indicate where in HA you can find stuff about it : there's example 1.3.3.5 which mentions it in the bounded below case; and then there's section 7.1.1. which culminates  in proposition 7.1.1.15. and remark 7.1.1.16., explaining how $D(R) \simeq Mod_R(Sp)$ via this functor.